# DART: Filter and Search not working correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and Dart, so this may be a silly issue.

I'm trying to add the ability to Search and Filter on some data that I'm getting from a public API (https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1). For some weird reason, when I filter on Gender I get mixed results. They are never correct.

I may filter on Male, and I'll get 5 Male records and one Female record at the tail in of the results. I'm also having issues getting the search feature to work as well. I'm pasting all of my code from my home.dart file. This should be enough, if not, let me know and I'll add more.

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:flutterapp/model/user_name.dart';
import '../model/user.dart';
import '../services/user_api.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<User> users = [];
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  final List<String> filterOptions = [
    'All',
    'Male',
    'Female',
  ];
  String selectedFilter = 'All';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchUsers();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Resting API Call'),
        centerTitle: mounted,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
        shadowColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _searchController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Search users...",
              ),
            ),
          ),
          DropdownButton(
            value: selectedFilter,
            items: filterOptions
                .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: e,
                      child: Text(e),
                    ))
                .toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedFilter = value as String;
              });
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              addRepaintBoundaries: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final user = users[index];
                // final email = user.email;
                final gender = user.gender;
                // final color = user.gender == 'male' ? Colors.blue : Colors.white10;
                final imageUrl = user.picture.thumbnail;
                // final searchText = _searchController.text;

                // bool isMatch = user.fullName
                //     .toLowerCase()
                //     .contains(searchText.toLowerCase());

                return Card(
                  elevation: 4,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(180),
                      child: Image.network(imageUrl),
                    ),
                    title: Text(user.fullName),
                    // subtitle: Text(user.location.country),
                    subtitle: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(user.location.fullStreetName),
                        Text(user.location.city),
                        Text(user.location.state),
                        Text(user.location.country),
                        Text(user.location.fullcoordinates),
                        Text(user.email),
                        Text(user.gender),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: users.where((user) {
                if (selectedFilter == 'All') {
                  return true;
                } else {
                  return user.gender == selectedFilter.toLowerCase();
                }
              }).length,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> fetchUsers() async {
    final response = await UserApi.fetchUsers();
    setState(() {
      users = response;
    });
  }
}`
```

In the below block of code, I would expect that if I select 'All', all of the records from my query would be present. If I select anything other than 'All, my query would then return records based on the filter.

```
itemCount: users.where((user) {
       if (selectedFilter == 'All') {
                  return true;
                } else {
                  return user.gender == selectedFilter.toLowerCase();
                }
              }).length,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `itemCount` property is used to specify the number of items in the list.

Please do the following instead:

Inside the `build` method, get a list of users according to the filter, and assign it to a variable:

```
final searchKeyword = _searchController.text.toLowerCase();
final filteredUsers = users.where((user) {
    // handle filter
    if (selectedFilter == 'All') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return user.gender == selectedFilter.toLowerCase();
    }
}).where((user) {
    // handle search
    return searchKeyword.isEmpty || user.fullName.toLowerCase().contains(searchKeyword);
}).toList();
```

Then provide it to the `ListView` widget:

```
ListView.builder(
    // ...
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final user = filteredUsers[index];
        // ...
    },
    itemCount: filteredUsers.length,
),
```

Comment: This solution fixed the Filtering issue. Any advice on the Search issue?

Comment: Sorry I missed the search issue. Updated the answer now, please take a look.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I'm all set!